# Disable dragging images on TinyMCE 4

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

How I can disable dragging images on TinyMCE 4? I use `jQuery`:

```
jQuery('#tinymce img').on('dragstart', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

but it not working...

Answer (score 12):

### Paste Plugin

I find some better solution to this. You can just use the `paste_block_drop` option from `paste` plugin like

```
tinymce.init({
    plugins: 'paste image',
    paste_block_drop: true
)};
```

And what this option does is simply **Enables you to block drag/drop from/to the editor and inside it**.

**NB:** Tested on version **4.7.4** though I didn't find it in their current(when I am answering) `paste` plugin [documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/paste/), Rather I found it in their archive [documentation](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin3x:paste) for version **4.3.12**

### PowerPaste Plugin

And if you are using **Power Paste Plugin** you can use the `powerpaste_block_drop: true` option instead that will disable all drag and dropping content into the editor. You will find documentation about this [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/powerpaste/) (*thanks to @Kurt from the comment*)

Comment: If you're using powerpaste plugin instead of paste, there's "powerpaste_block_drop"

Answer (score 1):

Use the tinymce configuration parameter `setup` and use a handler for this:

```
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('init', function(event) {

        $(editor.getBody().parentNode).bind('dragover dragenter dragend drag drop', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

       $(editor.getDoc()).bind('draggesture', function(e) {
           e.stopPropagation();
           e.preventDefault();

       });
    });
  }
```

Comment: glad to have been able to help